# Knockout binding multiple view models in a page by id

Tags: knockout.js

I am building a complex UI using twitter bootstrap and Knockout.js. To achieve this I have broken my page into a number of different logical components.

Is it okay to define a view model for each component and bind it by id , using

`ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('someElementId'))`

rather then defining a single view model and binding the entire page to that?Does it have any performance issues?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is fine to bind in this manner and it will not have worse performance.

When you are binding your subsections, you would want to make sure that you are not applying bindings to the same area more than once.  This can happen if you apply bindings to a parent element and then to a child.

If you need to do that (bind individual sections, but also an overall view model), then you would want to do something like this: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html

Comment: Thanks for the link to your blog! it has some very useful stuff.I suggest that you post that link on the official Knockout page.Man it would have answered a lot my questions if I knew about it :)

Comment: Yes, I think that we should consider adding a section on strategies for managing multiple view models to the official docs.